# Video Upload on Imgur PHP

Tags: php, imgur

I'm currently working on an Imgur API which should upload images, gifs and videos; images and gifs are being uploaded without any problems and are working fine.

My Problem is the video part, I always get an error similar to this:

```
{"data":{"error":"No image data was sent to the upload
  api","request":"\/3\/upload","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":400}
```

or this:

> Notice: Undefined index: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\localfile\php\upvideo.php on line 50 There's a Problem **No image data was sent to the upload api**

or I get an timeout response.

Since the API docs told me that I need to post it as a Binaryfile I tried using `fopen()`, `fread()`, `file_get_contents()` and countless more. Sadly none of them seem to give curl the string it wants if I use a video; it works just fine with images and gifs (which are now being sent as binary - before I used base64encode before passing it to curl).

I do know that there are 2 tags video and image which I change based on what I'm trying to send at the moment, but video always seems to give me the errors above.

Here is my code:

```php
<?php
    // the posted stuff from my form
    $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST["title"]);
    $posted = htmlspecialchars($_POST["token"]);
    $desc =  htmlspecialchars($_POST["desc"]);
    // data from the file i put into the form
    $fileName =  $_FILES["imglink"]["name"];
    $fileTmpName =  $_FILES["imglink"]["tmp_name"];
    $size = $_FILES["imglink"]["size"];
    // checks if everything is set and ready
    if ($title != "" && $desc != "" && is_string($posted)) {
        if($fileName == ''){  
          header("location: ../sub-pages/error.php?noimage");
         }else{

        /*$data = file_get_contents($fileTmpName);*/

        /*var_dump($data);*/

        // take the file temporary name and make it something binary..
        $handle = fopen($fileTmpName, "rb");
        $data = fread($handle, filesize($fileTmpName));
        //the curl function
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        // all the files i need imgur to get e.g the video (i change video to image if i want to post an image), name of the image etc.
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array( 'video' => @ $data, "type" => "file", "title" => $title, "description" => $desc, "name" => $fileName),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( "Authorization: Bearer ". $posted),
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $pms = json_decode($response, true);
        $url = $pms['data']['link'];
            if ($url!="") {
                echo "Posted";
                header("location: ../sub-pages/succes.php?link=". $url);
            } else {
                echo "<h2>There's a Problem</h2>";
                echo $pms['data']['error'];
            }
        }

    }
    else{
        echo "no";
    }?>
```

All answers to topic this seem to be outdated or not fixing this.

Comment: Did you try echoing the result of `$err = curl_error($curl);` There is not much point collecting the error if you are not going to base your next action on the state of the error

Comment: Yes i did do that in an older version of the programm, but at its current state it does not echo anything.
     echo $pms['data']['error'];
Bassicly replaces it

Comment: Video upload is broken. It always expects "image" keyword and when you send your video with "video" keyword it complains about the missing image. The solution is to contact imgur and let developers know about it.

Comment: So its not my fault for not working right? Alright thanks for the info! :)